# load <options> into <select> when <select> is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there no way to populate a `<select>` list when the `<select>` element is clicked on?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", "select", function(){
        ajax(); //should append additional <option>s to select
    });
});
```

Is there any solution for loading the content of the `<select>` when it is clicked on?

http://jsfiddle.net/AxEAe/

EDIT:

Tried surrounding `<select>` with a `<div>` and attaching click event to that. No luck.

Comment: your fiddle seems to be working

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Really? It's doesn't for me; it only shows the first two static options.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible, as demonstrated by your fiddle. Open and close it a few times. The problem is the select doesn't update till you close and reopen it again because ajax isn't instant. Why exactly do you want to do it on click?

Comment: @KevinB What browser are you using? I'm not having luck in chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: I tried in Chrome and Firefox and it works - It doesn't work in IE though

Comment: It won't work in IE<9 due to using jquery 2.0. I typically can't get jsfiddle to work at all in IE. I wouldn't trust IE testing in jsfiddle.

Comment: @KevinB ah.. no wonder didn't even notice that.. It actually doesn't work in IE10 either using jQuery 2.0

Comment: @KevinB I'm getting nowhere in Chrome. Did you change the fiddle in any other way?

Comment: @KevinB I can't even get it to work without ajax... http://jsfiddle.net/5Ud7N/  (chrome 28.0.1500.52)

Comment: @thomas That works for me too. Click it over and over. The first click doesn't appear to work, but when you click again, you see the result of the first click. Again, it's just a timing issue. Using click for this is a bad idea.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, no kidding. Thanks for they help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on("click", "select", function(){
        $(this).children('option:last').insertAfter('<option>Another option</option>');
});
```